Stripe Sigma - Connecting transfers to transfer reversals
I am writing a query on Stripe Sigma, to route transfers via Connected Accounts.
For context, the money from customers comes into our main stripe, we then transfer the relevant amount to the Franchisor or Franchisee respectively.
This query will calculate:

The original amount in
The amount sent to Franchisee
The amount sent to Franchisor

Looking at the descriptions of the transfers.
Q: I have already accurately calcualted the "Sum of Paid to Franchisor", how do I then calculate the total transfer reversals which are related, so I can have "Sum of Reversals from Franchisor"
The focus will be on charge_transfers

WITH date_range AS (
    SELECT 
        TIMESTAMP '2024-09-30 23:59:30' AS start_datetime, 
        TIMESTAMP '2024-11-01 00:00:00' AS end_datetime
), 
sms_charges AS (
    SELECT
        cat.account AS connected_account_id,
        SUM(c.amount) AS total_sms_charged,
        SUM(bt.net) AS net_sms
    FROM
        charges c
    JOIN
        connected_account_transfers cat ON c.source_transfer_id = cat.id
    JOIN
        balance_transactions bt ON c.balance_transaction_id = bt.id
    CROSS JOIN
        date_range dr
    WHERE
        c.description LIKE '%SMS Fee%'
        AND c.created >= dr.start_datetime
        AND c.created < dr.end_datetime
    GROUP BY
        cat.account
),
transfer_reversals_sum AS (
    SELECT 
        t.destination_id AS connected_account_id, 
        SUM(tr.amount) / 100.0 AS total_transfer_reversals 
    FROM 
        transfer_reversals tr 
    JOIN 
        transfers t ON tr.transfer_id = t.id 
    WHERE 
        tr.created >= (SELECT start_datetime FROM date_range) 
        AND tr.created < (SELECT end_datetime FROM date_range) 
    GROUP BY 
        t.destination_id
),
charge_transfers AS (
    SELECT
        ca.id AS connected_account_id,
        cam.value AS franchisee_id,
        ca.business_name AS connected_account_business_name,
        am.value AS tenant,
        ca.email AS connected_account_email,
        c.payment_intent,
        SUM(c.amount) AS total_charge_amount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.description LIKE '%Transfer to franchisor%' THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_franchisor_transfer_amount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.description LIKE '%Transfer to franchisee%' THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_franchisee_transfer_amount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.description LIKE '%Transfer to franchisor%' THEN tr.amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_franchisor_transfer_reversals
    FROM
        charges c
    JOIN
        transfers t ON c.id = t.source_transaction_id
    LEFT JOIN
        connected_accounts ca ON t.destination_id = ca.id
    LEFT JOIN
        connected_accounts_metadata am ON ca.id = am.account_id AND am.key = 'tenant'
    LEFT JOIN
        connected_accounts_metadata cam ON ca.id = cam.account_id AND cam.key = 'franchisee_id'
    LEFT JOIN
        connected_accounts_metadata cam2 ON ca.id = cam.account_id AND cam.key = 'transaction_percentage'
    LEFT JOIN
        connected_accounts_metadata cam3 ON ca.id = cam.account_id AND cam.key = 'transaction_pence'
    LEFT JOIN
        transfer_reversals tr ON t.id = tr.transfer_id
    CROSS JOIN
        date_range dr
    WHERE
        c.created >= dr.start_datetime
        AND c.created < dr.end_datetime
        AND (t.description LIKE '%Transfer to franchisee%' OR t.description LIKE '%Transfer to franchisor%')
    GROUP BY
        ca.id,
        cam.value,
        ca.business_name,
        am.value,
        ca.email,
        c.payment_intent
),
payment_intent_transfers AS (
    SELECT
        ct.payment_intent,
        SUM(ct.total_franchisor_transfer_amount) / 100.0 AS formatted_total_franchisor_transfer_amount,
        SUM(ct.total_franchisee_transfer_amount) / 100.0 AS formatted_total_franchisee_transfer_amount
    FROM
        charge_transfers ct
    GROUP BY
        ct.payment_intent
),
combined_transfers AS (
    SELECT
        ct.connected_account_id,
        SUM(ct.total_charge_amount) / 100.0 AS formatted_total_charge_amount,
        SUM(pit.formatted_total_franchisor_transfer_amount) AS formatted_total_franchisor_transfer_amount,
        SUM(pit.formatted_total_franchisee_transfer_amount) AS formatted_total_franchisee_transfer_amount,
        SUM(ct.total_franchisor_transfer_reversals) / 100.0 AS total_franchisor_transfer_reversals
    FROM
        charge_transfers ct
    LEFT JOIN
        payment_intent_transfers pit ON ct.payment_intent = pit.payment_intent
    GROUP BY
        ct.connected_account_id
),
subscription_charges AS (
    SELECT
        cat.account AS connected_account_id,
        SUM(c.amount) AS total_subscription_charged
    FROM
        charges c
    JOIN
        connected_account_transfers cat ON c.source_transfer_id = cat.id
    CROSS JOIN
        date_range dr
    WHERE
        c.description LIKE '%Subscription Charge%'
        AND c.created >= dr.start_datetime
        AND c.created < dr.end_datetime
    GROUP BY
        cat.account
),
dispute_charges AS (
    SELECT
        cat.account AS connected_account_id,
        SUM(c.amount) AS total_dispute_charges
    FROM
        charges c
    JOIN
        connected_account_transfers cat ON c.source_transfer_id = cat.id
    CROSS JOIN
        date_range dr
    WHERE
        c.description LIKE '%Dispute%'
        AND c.created >= dr.start_datetime
        AND c.created < dr.end_datetime
    GROUP BY
        cat.account
),
monthly_fee_net AS (
    SELECT
        cat.account AS connected_account_id,
        SUM(bt.net) / 100.0 AS formatted_net_subscription_fee
    FROM
        connected_account_transfers cat
    JOIN
        charges c ON cat.destination_payment_id = c.id
    JOIN
        balance_transactions bt ON c.balance_transaction_id = bt.id
    WHERE
        c.description LIKE '%Subscription Charge%'
        AND c.created >= (SELECT start_datetime FROM date_range)
        AND c.created < (SELECT end_datetime FROM date_range)
    GROUP BY
        cat.account
),
corrections_transfers AS (
    SELECT
        cac.account AS connected_account_id,
        SUM(cac.amount) / 100.0 AS sum_of_corrections
    FROM
        connected_account_charges cac
    WHERE
        (cac.description IS NULL OR cac.description = '')  
        AND cac.created >= (SELECT start_datetime FROM date_range)
        AND cac.created < (SELECT end_datetime FROM date_range)
    GROUP BY
        cac.account
),
connect_collections_transfers AS (
    SELECT
        cat.account AS connected_account_id,
        SUM(t.amount) / 100.0 AS sum_of_connect_collections
    FROM
        transfers t
    JOIN
        connected_account_transfers cat ON t.id = cat.id
    WHERE
        t.description LIKE '%connect_collection_transfer%'
        AND t.created >= (SELECT start_datetime FROM date_range)
        AND t.created < (SELECT end_datetime FROM date_range)
    GROUP BY
        cat.account
),
refund_fees AS (
    SELECT
        cat.account AS connected_account_id,
        SUM(c.amount) AS total_refund_fees,
        SUM(bt.net) AS net_refunds -- Correctly aggregate and alias this column
    FROM
        charges c
    JOIN
        connected_account_transfers cat ON c.source_transfer_id = cat.id
    JOIN
        balance_transactions bt ON c.balance_transaction_id = bt.id
    CROSS JOIN
        date_range dr
    WHERE
        c.description LIKE '%Company fees%'
        AND c.created >= dr.start_datetime
        AND c.created < dr.end_datetime
    GROUP BY
        cat.account
),
refunds_from_table AS (
    SELECT
        c.on_behalf_of_id AS connected_account_id,
        SUM(r.amount) AS total_refunds
    FROM
        refunds r
    JOIN
        charges c ON r.charge_id = c.id
    CROSS JOIN
        date_range dr
    WHERE
        r.created >= dr.start_datetime
        AND r.created < dr.end_datetime
    GROUP BY
        c.on_behalf_of_id
),
dispute_net AS (
    SELECT
        cat.account AS connected_account_id,
        SUM(bt.net) / 100.0 AS total_dispute_net
    FROM
        connected_account_transfers cat
    JOIN
        charges c ON cat.destination_payment_id = c.id
    JOIN
        balance_transactions bt ON c.balance_transaction_id = bt.id
    WHERE
        c.description LIKE '%Dispute%'
        AND c.created >= (SELECT start_datetime FROM date_range)
        AND c.created < (SELECT end_datetime FROM date_range)
    GROUP BY
        cat.account
),
charges_with_no_transfers AS (
    SELECT
        c.on_behalf_of_id AS connected_account_id,
        COUNT(c.id) AS charges_with_no_transfers
    FROM
        charges c
    LEFT JOIN
        transfers t ON c.id = t.source_transaction_id
    WHERE
        c.created >= (SELECT start_datetime FROM date_range)
        AND c.created < (SELECT end_datetime FROM date_range)
        AND t.id IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        c.on_behalf_of_id
),
combined_data AS (
    SELECT
    ct.connected_account_id,
    ca.email AS connected_account_email,
    cam.value AS franchisee_id,
    am.value AS tenant,
    cam2.value AS transaction_percentage,
    cam3.value AS transaction_pence,
    ct.formatted_total_charge_amount,
    ct.formatted_total_franchisor_transfer_amount,
    ct.formatted_total_franchisee_transfer_amount,
    COALESCE(sc.total_subscription_charged, 0) / 100.0 AS formatted_total_subscription_charged,
    COALESCE(sm.total_sms_charged, 0) / 100.0 AS formatted_total_sms_charged,
    COALESCE(sm.net_sms, 0) / 100.0 AS formatted_net_sms,
    COALESCE(rf.net_refunds, 0) / 100.0 AS formatted_net_refund_fees,
    COALESCE(rft.total_refunds, 0) / 100.0 AS formatted_total_refunds,
    COALESCE(dn.total_dispute_net, 0) AS formatted_dispute_net,
    COALESCE(dc.total_dispute_charges, 0) / 100.0 AS formatted_total_dispute_charges,
    (ct.formatted_total_charge_amount - 
     (COALESCE(ct.formatted_total_franchisee_transfer_amount, 0) + 
     COALESCE(ct.formatted_total_franchisor_transfer_amount, 0))) AS formatted_company_fees,
    COALESCE(mf.formatted_net_subscription_fee, 0) AS formatted_net_subscription_fee,
    COALESCE(cor.sum_of_corrections, 0) AS formatted_sum_of_corrections,
    COALESCE(cc.sum_of_connect_collections, 0) AS formatted_sum_of_connect_collections,
    (COALESCE(mf.formatted_net_subscription_fee, 0) + 
     (ct.formatted_total_charge_amount - 
     (COALESCE(ct.formatted_total_franchisee_transfer_amount, 0) + 
     COALESCE(ct.formatted_total_franchisor_transfer_amount, 0)))) AS formatted_sum_of_net,
    COALESCE(trs.total_transfer_reversals, 0) AS total_transfer_reversals,
    SUM(ct.total_franchisor_transfer_reversals) AS total_franchisor_transfer_reversals
FROM
    combined_transfers ct
LEFT JOIN
    connected_accounts ca ON ct.connected_account_id = ca.id
LEFT JOIN
    connected_accounts_metadata am ON ca.id = am.account_id AND am.key = 'tenant'
LEFT JOIN
    connected_accounts_metadata cam ON ca.id = cam.account_id AND cam.key = 'franchisee_id'
LEFT JOIN
    connected_accounts_metadata cam2 ON ca.id = cam.account_id AND cam.key = 'transaction_percentage'
LEFT JOIN
    connected_accounts_metadata cam3 ON ca.id = cam.account_id AND cam.key = 'transaction_pence'
LEFT JOIN
    subscription_charges sc ON ct.connected_account_id = sc.connected_account_id
LEFT JOIN
    dispute_charges dc ON ct.connected_account_id = dc.connected_account_id
LEFT JOIN
    sms_charges sm ON ct.connected_account_id = sm.connected_account_id
LEFT JOIN
    refund_fees rf ON ct.connected_account_id = rf.connected_account_id
LEFT JOIN
    refunds_from_table rft ON ct.connected_account_id = rft.connected_account_id
LEFT JOIN
    dispute_net dn ON ct.connected_account_id = dn.connected_account_id
LEFT JOIN
    monthly_fee_net mf ON ct.connected_account_id = mf.connected_account_id
LEFT JOIN
    corrections_transfers cor ON ct.connected_account_id = cor.connected_account_id
LEFT JOIN
    connect_collections_transfers cc ON ct.connected_account_id = cc.connected_account_id
LEFT JOIN
    transfer_reversals_sum trs ON ct.connected_account_id = trs.connected_account_id
  
  GROUP BY
    ct.connected_account_id,
    ca.email,
    cam.value,
    am.value,
    cam2.value,
    cam3.value,
    ct.formatted_total_charge_amount,
    ct.formatted_total_franchisor_transfer_amount,
    ct.formatted_total_franchisee_transfer_amount,
    sc.total_subscription_charged,
    sm.total_sms_charged,
    sm.net_sms,
    rf.net_refunds,
    rft.total_refunds,
    dn.total_dispute_net,
    dc.total_dispute_charges,
    mf.formatted_net_subscription_fee,
    cor.sum_of_corrections,
    cc.sum_of_connect_collections,
    trs.total_transfer_reversals
)

SELECT
    connected_account_id,
    connected_account_email,  -- Include email in the final SELECT
    tenant as "Tenant",  -- Include tenant value in the SELECT
    transaction_percentage as "Fees_Percentage",
    transaction_pence as "Fees_Pence",
    formatted_total_charge_amount AS "Sum of Sale",
    ROUND(formatted_total_refunds, 2) AS "Sum of Refund",
    formatted_net_sms AS "Sum of TEXTS",
    ROUND(formatted_sum_of_corrections, 2) AS "Sum of Corrections Last Mth",
    ROUND(formatted_sum_of_connect_collections, 2) AS "Sum of Connect Collections",
    formatted_net_refund_fees AS "Sum of Frans Fees on Refunds",
    ROUND(formatted_total_franchisee_transfer_amount - total_transfer_reversals, 2) AS "Sum of Paid to Franchisee",
    ROUND(formatted_total_franchisor_transfer_amount, 2) AS "Sum of Paid to Franchisor",
    formatted_dispute_net AS "Sum of Disputes Net",
    formatted_total_dispute_charges AS "Sum of Dispute Charges",
    COALESCE(formatted_net_subscription_fee, 0) AS "Sum of Monthly Fee",
    ROUND(formatted_company_fees, 2) AS "Sum of Calculates fees on sales",
    formatted_total_subscription_charged AS "Sum of Corrected Monthly Fee",
    ROUND(formatted_sum_of_net + formatted_net_sms, 2) AS "Sum of Net",
    total_transfer_reversals AS "Transfer Reversals",
       total_franchisor_transfer_reversals AS "Franchisor Transfer Reversals"
FROM
    combined_data
WHERE
    connected_account_id = 'XYZ'
ORDER BY
    tenant;


I have included my attempt via total_franchisor_transfer_reversals, however I believe the issue is that the transfer reversal is not under connected account XYZ, it's under the franchisors account.

CROSS JOIN, but join conditions in the WHERE clause? What's wrong with a basic JOIN?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Try reaching out to Stripe Support at https://support.stripe.com/contact
